# jQuery plugin - how to access this.el in prototype

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

We are changing our core jQuery plugin template.  Below is a mock sample.  The problem I'm having is:

1. I declare this.el and this.$el in the closure Plugin
2. Yet, I need access to each of these in the prototype in order to pass it to the private functions.

How do we get access to this that is within the closure Plugin??

```
;(function( $, window, document, undefined ){
    var pluginName = 'myPlugin',
        defaults = {
            data    : null,
            el      : null,
            $el     : null
        }

    function Plugin(el, options) {
        this.el = el;
        this.$el = $(el);

        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults; 
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.methods.init();
    }

    $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
        methods: {
            init: function() {
                functions._addInput.call(this);
            },
            destroy: function () {
                console.log('in public destroy');

                this.$el.removeData();
            },
            testMessage: function() {
                console.log('in public testMessage()');
            },
            inputHandler: function(value) {
                functions._inputHandler(value);
            }
        }
    });        

    /*
    ----------------------------
    PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
    ----------------------------
     */

    var functions = {
        _addInput: function() {
            var $this = this;

            console.log('adding input');
            var input = '<input type="text" class="myplugin-input">';
            $this.$el.append(input);
        },
        _testMessage: function() {
            console.log('in the private testMessage()');
        },
        _inputHandler: function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        }
    };

    //* Plugin Function
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0),
            options,
            base,
            method, value,
            allowedMethods = ["destroy", "testMessage", "inputHandler"];

        this.each(function(){
            if (args.length === 0 || typeof args[0] === 'object')
            {
                if ( ! $.data( this, pluginName))
                {
                    options = args.length === 0 ? {} : $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, args[0]);
                    options.el = $(this);
                    $.data( this, pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
                }
            }
            else if (typeof args[0] === 'string')
            {
                if ( ! args[0] in allowedMethods) throw 'Unknown method ' + args[0] + ' passed to myPlugin';

                base = $.data(this, pluginName);
                if (base === undefined) return this;

                method = args[0];
                base.methods[method].apply(base, args.slice(1));
            }
            else
            {
                throw 'Invalid arguments pased to myPlugin plugin ' + args;
            }

            return (value === undefined) ? this : value;
        });

    };

    $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
        data : null,
        el : null,
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is an oddity to me:

```
$.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
    methods: {
        //
    }
});
```

Besides using `$.extend` without cause (the prototype didn't have any existing properties to worry about overwriting/augmenting), you put all the object instance's functions in a property named `methods`.

Write it as follows:

```
Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        functions._addInput.call(this);
    },
    destroy: function () {
        console.log('in public destroy');

        this.$el.removeData();
    },
    testMessage: function () {
        console.log('in public testMessage()');
    },
    inputHandler: function (value) {
        functions._inputHandler(value);
    }
};
```

This will avoid the unnecessary overhead of `$.extend`, will put your methods where they belong--right on the prototype--and make all of your instance properties (`this.el`, etc.) available in the instance methods (methods contained in the prototype).

Comment: @JAAudle. I knew it was a silly error.  That structure was carried over from another layout.  Works perfectly.  Thank you for pointing it

Comment: No problem, I suspected it was a hold over from another paradigm. :)